# Append multiple array values into single value

Tags: php, arrays

I have two PHP arrays, and would like to append the value of the first array to the second array to create a new array which reiterates the original order but combines both values. I have tried the PHP array_merge but this just appends the new array but not merge into single values.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Item 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Item 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Item 3
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => Item 4
        )
)
```

Second array;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [count] => 3
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [count] => 6
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [count] => 9
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [count] => 2
        )
)
```

Completed array;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title_count] => Item 1 (3)
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [title_count] => Item 2 (6)
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [title_count] => Item 3 (9)
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [title_count] => Item 4 (2)
        )
)
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-in that will do this. You'll have to write a loop that does it. I've never before seen the need to concatenate array keys like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `foreach` loop.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array1 as $i => $element) {
    $title = $element['title'];
    $count = $array2[$i]['count'];
    $result[] = array('title_count' => "$title ($count)");
}
```